# org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: com.domaine.AnomalieAck

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hibernate-mapping, instantiation

I am trying to persist an enum Value into the database, but an instantiation exception is triggered, here  is my mapping :

```
@Entity
public class Anomalie {

    @Embedded
    private AnomalieAck ack = AnomalieAck.NON_ACQUITTEE;



    public Anomalie() {
    }
/*getters and setters*/
}
```

//AnomalieAck.java

```
public enum AnomalieAck {

    NON_ACQUITTEE(0),

    ACQUITTEE_APP1 (1),

    ACQUITTEE_APP2(2),

    /** Aacquittee en erreur. */
    ACQUITTEE_ERREUR(10),

    @Column(name = "ANO_ACK")
    private int ack = 0;

  private AnomalieAck() {

    }

  private AnomalieAck(final int value) {
    this.ack = value;
   }
  public int getValue() {
        return this.ack;
    }
  public void setAck(int ack) {
        this.ack = ack;
    }
}
```

The reason why I didn't use the `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` or `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` is that in the database the field **ANO_ACK** is declared as the number and there are a lot of other resources that use this value as Number.

I have checked everything: the no-args constructor is already defined, the setter method is implemented.

What can I do to let Hibernate instantiate this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not embed an enum.

What you need here is a custom converter:

**Converter**:

```
@Converter
public class AnomalieAckConverter implements AttributeConverter<AnomalieAck , Integer> {

 @Override
 public String convertToDatabaseColumn(AnomalieAck  anomalieAck ) {
   return anomalieAck.getValue();
 }

 @Override
 public AnomalieAck convertToEntityAttribute(Integer ack) {
    retrun AnomalieAck.getByValue(ack);
 }

}
```

**Entity:**

```
@Column
@Convert(converter = AnomalieAckConverter.class)
private AnomalieAck ack;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but should i create the   AttributeConverter interface ?

Comment: No. That is part of the javax.persistence package

Comment: you may need to add hibernate-jpa-2.1-api dependency to you project

Comment: It's working thank you so much, but in the database when the value of ack is persisted it takes the ordinal value instead of the value itself. What can i Do to save the value instead of Ordinal? Its working as if i used (EnumType.Ordinal)

Comment: create a getAck method in enum and use that instead

Comment: I did that, the name of the method in my class is getValue() and i can't rename it cause its used in other external products. Can you please see why its pesisting the ordinal value.

Comment: "Do not embed an enum" - why that and what is the `@Enumerated` annotation for then?

Answer (score 0):

Enum class

```
public enum AnomalieAck {

    NON_ACQUITTEE(0),

    ACQUITTEE_APP1 (1),

    ACQUITTEE_APP2(2),

    /** Aacquittee en erreur. */
    ACQUITTEE_ERREUR(10),


    private int ack = 0;

  private AnomalieAck() {

    }

  private AnomalieAck(final int value) {
    this.ack = value;
   }
  public int getValue() {
        return this.ack;
    }

  public void setAck(int ack) {
        this.ack = ack;
    }

public static AnomalieAck getByValue(int ackNumero) {
    for (final AnomalieAck ackitement : AnomalieAck.values()) {

        if (ackitement.getValue() == ackNumero) {
            return ackitement;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

Converter :

```
public class AnomalieAckConverter implements AttributeConverter<AnomalieAck, Integer> {

    /**
     * @param attribute
     * @return
     * @see javax.persistence.AttributeConverter#convertToDatabaseColumn(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(AnomalieAck anoAck) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return anoAck.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @param dbData
     * @return
     * @see javax.persistence.AttributeConverter#convertToEntityAttribute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public AnomalieAck convertToEntityAttribute(Integer ack) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return AnomalieAck.getByValue(ack);

    }
```

The solution is working but it persists the ordinal value instead of its int value, the getAck is getValue()